# laravel dusk error when testing on github actions

Tags: laravel-6, github-actions, laravel-dusk

i've project that using dusk for simple admin login testing. everything work's fine when i doing login admin test case on local machine(my own local computer).

here my `DuskTestCase.php` snippet:

```php
...
    protected function driver()
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless',
            '--window-size=1920,1080',
        ]);

        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://localhost:9515', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
                ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
            )
        );
    }
...
```

my `LoginTest.php` snippet located in `test/Browser`:

```php
...
    public function testLoginAdmin()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/login')
                    ->type('#email', 'admin@admin')
                    ->type('#password', 'admin')
                    ->press('LOGIN')
                    ->assertPathIs('/admin/dasbor');;
        });
    }
...
```

here's the output from my local computer:

```sh
$ php artisan dusk
Warning: TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.
PHPUnit 9.2.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:63025/devtools/browser/26e3002f-4050-4549-9220-246558a7efd6
.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 00:08.528, Memory: 16.00 MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

but it's going error when i run github actions.
my `.env.dusk` file:

```
APP_NAME="Pins SmartPJU"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:8CpKYwb2PE3aRhzRUwh3XMg/+VwlLVM1B0AqhyhR8B0=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=database/database.sqlite
...
///the rest is default
```

here's the yml:

```yml
name: dusk testing

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  laravel-tests:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Copy .env
      run: php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.dusk', '.env');"
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: composer install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress --prefer-dist
    - name: Generate key
      run: php artisan key:generate
    - name: Directory Permissions
      run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
    - name: Upgrade Chrome Driver
      run: php artisan dusk:chrome-driver 70
    - name: Start Chrome Driver
      run: ./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    - name: Run Dusk Tests
      run: |
        php artisan serve > /dev/null 2>&1 &
        chmod -R 0755 vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/
        php artisan dusk
```

and last, the error output

```sh
Run php artisan serve > /dev/null 2>&1 &
Warning: TTY mode requires /dev/tty to be read/writable.
PHPUnit 9.2.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 01:22.789, Memory: 18.00 MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Browser\LoginTest::testLoginAdmin
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session/5e36290494b538df79cb44f5a5b7b459/log with params: {"type":"browser"}

Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

/home/runner/work/pins-pju/pins-pju/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:331
/home/runner/work/pins-pju/pins-pju/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:590
/home/runner/work/pins-pju/pins-pju/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteExecuteMethod.php:27
/home/runner/work/pins-pju/pins-pju/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/WebDriverOptions.php:166
/home/runner/work/pins-pju/pins-pju/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Browser.php:396
/home/runner/work/pins-pju/pins-pju/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:161
/home/runner/work/pins-pju/pins-pju/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php:176
/home/runner/work/pins-pju/pins-pju/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:162
/home/runner/work/pins-pju/pins-pju/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:78
/home/runner/work/pins-pju/pins-pju/tests/Browser/LoginTest.php:24

Caused by
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http GET to /session/5e36290494b538df79cb44f5a5b7b459/screenshot

Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

/home/runner/work/pins-pju/pins-pju/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:331
/home/runner/work/pins-pju/pins-pju/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:590
/home/runner/work/pins-pju/pins-pju/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:371
/home/runner/work/pins-pju/pins-pju/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Browser.php:382
/home/runner/work/pins-pju/pins-pju/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:146
/home/runner/work/pins-pju/pins-pju/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php:176
/home/runner/work/pins-pju/pins-pju/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:147
/home/runner/work/pins-pju/pins-pju/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:70
/home/runner/work/pins-pju/pins-pju/tests/Browser/LoginTest.php:24

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Errors: 1.
##[error]Process completed with exit code 2.
```

previously, i've trying to change the chrome driver version with `php artisan dusk:chrome-driver` and `php artisan dusk:chrome-driver 70`. It's still error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to add a step to run the migrations.
I have something similar to you but with that extra step:

```
      - name: Upgrade Chrome Driver
        run: php artisan dusk:chrome-driver `/opt/google/chrome/chrome --version | cut -d " " -f3 | cut -d "." -f1`
      - name: Run Migrations
        run: php artisan migrate
      - name: Change permissions to dusk
        run: chmod -R 0755 vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/ 
      - name: Run Laravel Server
        run: php artisan serve  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
      - name: curl to localhost
        run: curl localhost:8000 &
      - name: Start Chrome Driver
        run: ./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux > /dev/null 2>&1 &
      - name: Run Dusk Tests
        run: php artisan dusk
```

I also added a curl command to test if the application is up a running.

Comment: what is the intended use of `&`?
like `php artisan migrate &`

Comment: The & in the line of migrations is not needed, because the changes will impact in the database and the command actually ends. The other commands need the & to make they run in background and prevent the job to stuck.  I'll edit the answer, there are some repeated lines.